# Grey Edges on Image and Black Streaks in Corners

Tags: eevee-render-engine

First off, sorry if this is the wrong place to post this sort of thing.

I’m having some visual issues I’m trying to fix. I’ve attached a Render Image, the Render Tab Settings, Node Map and settings for the material

- On the left side, you can see a grey line on the edge of the render image near the windows. Upon further inspection, the grey patch maintains consistency as long as there is a window on the edge of the render image.
- The mini-extension in the rear has a little bit of light bleed. Does anyone know how to use Irradiance Volumes in non-cuboid spaces?
- Resolved issue with black streaks where floor and wall joined is caused by lack of irradiance volume density; Increase the density to solve issue (https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTcON.jpg 1)

Thanks a bunch!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure, how the lighting is set up, but the black streaks seem to be coming from the window panels. If your light source is small or close-by it will create harsher shadows. There also seems to be some light bleed. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2VNztZdfGZY&t=1382s) should help you with most problems when doing archivis in eevee

Comment: The black streaks were caused by the low density irradiance volume light probe I was using. The bright room extension was caused by the IV light probe not enclosing the entire space. However, the light probe is now partially outside of the space which bring in a little light bleed. I've edit my post to show the results and settings